# Compile iOS app against older Mono framework version in Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I'd like to debug my iOS app using an older version of the Mono framework so that I can see how things behaved with an older version of the Mono.Data.Sqlite assembly.

How can I tell Xamarin Studio to use an older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign `MD_MTOUCH_SDK_ROOT` to point to an alternative install location. This should be the root directory that contains `bin/mtouch`.

- You can set/export this as an env. variable to points to your alternative `Xamarin.iOS` framework and then launch Xamarin Studio (or VS4M) from the same shell.
- Or you could assign it within your `.csproj` file.

Ref: `Xamarin.MonoTouch.CSharp.targets`

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade to an earlier version of Xamarin simply by running an older installer. Here's more information on where to find the installers and how to use them: [How do I downgrade to an older version of Xamarin?](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-)